# how to declare dynamic variables in javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables

I have a field named tags. The input to this field can be any number of strings,depending on the user.And I need to store those strings in separate variable names. I tried something like this:

```
var tagsInputArray = ["a", "b"......n elements];
var tagsLength = tagsInputArray.length;
var count = 0;
for (count; count < tagsLength; count++) {
    var tags[count] = tagsInputArray[count];
}
```

This is not working.
How can I do it in jQuery?

Comment: What does that have to do with jQuery?

Comment: @Amit
Im working in jQuery. So i tagged it jQuery. Is there any other tags that I can use for generic doubts like this?. Im new to stackOverFlow.

Comment: @ArunMohan `I need to store those strings in separate variable names` What do you mean by this? Give an example

Comment: @Tushar
Say i have 4 elements in tagsArray like this
tagsArray = ["india","pakisthan","china","bangladesh"]
I need to get store each element in a variable like this:
var country1 = "india";
var country2 = "pakisthan";
var country3 = "china";
var country4 = "bangladesh";

Answer (score 2):

`length` is not defined anywhere you probably need to use `tagsLength` in loop

```
for(count;count<tagsLength ;count++){
```

You also have error for `var tags[count] = tagsInputArray[count];` as this is wrong syntax for declaring array. Removing the var key word would  remove the error and your code would work.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a9wono6m/2/)

```
var tagsInputArray = ["a", "b"];
var tagsLength = tagsInputArray.length;
var count = 0;
var tags = [];
for (count; count < tagsLength; count++)
     tags[count] = tagsInputArray[count];

for (count = 0; count < tags.length; count++)
  alert(tags[count]);
```

I would also recommend to use .push to add array element to other array, see this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a9wono6m/1/).

```
tags.push(tagsInputArray[count]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var tagsInputArray = ["a", "b"......n elements];

var tags = [];
for (var count = 0; count < tagsInputArray.length; count++) {
    tags[count] = tagsInputArray[count];
}

console.log(tags);
```

The problem with your code is that

```
var tags[count] = tagsInputArray[count];
```

inside `for` loop, `tags` is `undefined` and you are adding elements inside it. I've solved it by defining `tags` as array before `for` loop and then inserted elements inside it.